# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'eth')

Tags: solidity, contract-development, javascript

I am following what seems a relatively simple tutorial to create a smartcontract, however, I am getting the above error and I am stumped as to what is causing it

Below is my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Web 3 Demo</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>

    <script src='node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>

    Web 3 Demo
    <br >
    <button onclick="printCoolNumber();">Print Cool Number</button>
    <button onclick="changeCoolNumber();">Change Cool Number</button>
    <br /><br />
    Status: <span id="status">Loading...</span>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">

        async function loadContract()
        {
            return await new window.web3.eth.Contract(
            [
                {
                    "inputs": 
                    [
                        {
                            "internalType": "uint256",
                            "name": "_coolNumber",
                            "type": "uint256"
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "setCoolNumber",
                    "outputs": [],
                    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                    "type": "function"
                },
                {
                    "inputs": [],
                    "name": "coolNumber",
                    "outputs": 
                    [
                        {
                            "internalType": "uint256",
                            "name": "",
                            "type": "uint256"
                        }
                    ],
                    "stateMutability": "view",
                    "type": "function"
                }
            ], 0x80bA34870daee123d963e3C3EA2446aCd5dD668A);
        }
        
        async function loadWeb3()
        {
            if (window.ethereum)
            {
                window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
                window.ethereum.enable();
            }
        }
        
        async function load()
        {
            await loadWeb3();
            window.contract = await loadContract();
            updateStatus('Ready!');
        }
        
        function updateStatus(status)
        {
            const statusEl = document.getElementById('status');
            statusEl.innerHTML = status;
            console.log(status);
        }
        
        load();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The error itself occurs on line 26 with the call to
`return await new window.web3.eth.Contract(`

Running on windows and simple loading the index.html fro the browser with the following syntax

`file:///C:/users/<username>/documents/index.html`

From command line I have also run

npm install web3
import Web3 from 'web3'

So I think I've done everything correctly but wondered if anyone could help please.

Comment: For security reasons when showing an html file the browser might disable some functionality. Can you try serving the html file by http server instead?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is you are not serving your HTML content from a server rather you are just opening it using `file:///`

metamask gives or injects `new window.web3` only when it is served over HTTP or https. So in your case there won't be the scope hence facing the error.

Hope this helps you!!!